# Backup / Restore wordpress site (change domain)

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a wordpress based website on localhost. I wanted to migrate that on to www.mydomain.com. I checked in all the files from /var/www/wordpress from my localhost to a svn repository. And at the www.mydomain.com, I did a svn checkout. I also exported the wordpress database and imported it to my new domain.

I am using Graphene theme.

I modified all localhost in wp_options table to my domain name. Got it working, but noticed a few things missing.

- Mapping of my 3 menus, main, secondary and footer
- A post that I added for my side bar plugin at my localhost, is missing on my new domain
- Background color setting from Appearance->Background

Am I missing something ? A folder or something else ?

Edit : Also just read 
http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2005/12/01/search-and-replace-in-wordpress-mysql-database/

Comment: No i do not think so .. all is well... is there any issue?

Comment: Yeah, the bullet points above hint at a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I modified all localhost in wp_options table to my domain name

How did you do that? In a text editor with the database dump? That will break some data in the database.

It's best to use queries in phpmyadmin to change URLs in the database. Use:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

Use phpmyadmin at your webhost or use it as a plugin; see [WordPress › Portable phpMyAdmin « WordPress Plugins.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/)

**But it's even better to use** [interconnectit.com WordPress Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) that correctly deserializes/reserialize data in the database, as using the plain queries above can break serialized data.

And see [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: Yes, with a text editor. But why will it break ? I used a text editor since I was not able to find a way to do a search a replace (recursively). I had to do a search and then manually one by one do a update. Painful.. And yes, I did read the "moving wordpress" site.

Comment: The find/replace in the DB dump will break serialized data stored in menus and widget settings. That's just an issue with WP. Use phpmyadmin at your webhost or use it as a plugin, as noted above.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, what if I do a replace one by one, carefully examining every replace that I do ?

Comment: I found some entries like "mysqli_connect( &#39;<em>localhost</em>&#39;,", I guess this is what you meant by serialized content. So I replaced http:\\localhost with http:\\ec2dns and it worked ok.