# Replace localhost in wordpress paths

Tags: wordpress

I have installed wordpress on a windows machine running xampp on my lan, all running nicely.

for testing purposes etc I would like to view on another machine on the network I have created the virtual host and edited the hosts file.  the page will now view ok but wont apply any css and images appear as broken links, using firebug I can see that paths etc are referencing localhost, I realise that this is incorrect.

I have found this webpage and have created an entry [edit wp-config](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content)
Now some of the urls are showing the ip address.

This is the line I included `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/wordpress' );`

but not everything.[screen dump some urls showing local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XN0V.png)

What else do I need to change, so all the url show the IP address instead of localhost.

thanks for all help

I have now updated the localhost entries in the mysql database from localhost to 192.168.1.79 and this is now showing correctly in urls in girebug, I am still getting a 404 error though on everything else.

my httpd.conf contains `<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>` and the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

I am unsure what else to change

Comment: You need to search-replace domain in your database.

Comment: You can use [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) for that. It works nicely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backup / Restore wordpress site (change domain)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073516/backup-restore-wordpress-site-change-domain)